# Conditionally merge multiple rows in multiple Word tables

Tags: merge, row

I have an MS WORD 2019 file generated by opening PDF file. There are around one thousand tables with varied number of rows, and same number of columns. Some columns are already vertically merged based on serial number, some columns not merged vertically yet. In the first column, there are either cells filled with serial number or blank cells.

My aim is to use a macro to vertically merge all the cells under one serial number in column 8 into one cell based on the first column (serial number column), so that under each serial number, contents in column 8 will be displayed in one cell only.

I'm using the following macro to do the task. However, the macro usually works on a few tables only and will stop at the line of 'pos = oTbl.Cell(STARTROW, 8).Range.Start' most of the time, sometimes, it stops at the line: 'posEnd = oTbl.Cell(endrow, 8).Range.End', or sometimes the macro finished running all the tables, but some tables are merged, some are not merged. The error is: "Run-time error '5941': the requested member of the collection does not exist." Maybe there are minute differences between different tables as the file is generated from PDF file, but the difference, if any, cannot be seen from the tables. I feel puzzled at the macro running results. Any friend here can give some idea will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ConditionalMergeCellsVertically()

Dim oCell1 As Range, oCell2 As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim oTbl As Word.Table
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

  For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.count
  'determine first row (the row with serial number) to merge
  If oTbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text <> Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
  STARTROW = i
     For j = 1 To 30
     ' determine last row (the row above next serial number) to merge
     If oTbl.Cell(i + j, 1).Range.Text <> Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
     endrow = i + j - 1

     'merge cells 
     pos = oTbl.Cell(STARTROW, 8).Range.Start
     posEnd = oTbl.Cell(endrow, 8).Range.End
     Set myRange = ActiveDocument. _
     Range(Start:=pos, End:=posEnd)
     myRange.Select
     myRange.Cells.merge

     Exit For
     End If
     Next j

  End If
  i = i + j - 1
  Next i
 
Next oTbl

End Sub
```